# Numpy and Matplotlib Package Installation issue on amazon EC2

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am facing an issue with importing matplotlib and numpy packages

```
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I know that this has been addressed but in my case i do see this package on console

On the console, i am able to succesfully import matplotlib. I am confused as there are 2 python 2.7 folders. One under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` and there is a folder called dist-packages under it.

The matplotlib packages are located here

There is one more folder under `/usr/lib/python2.7`
I am not sure which folder iPython is looking at.

Kindly help me at the earliest. I am a newbie to python and especially linux.

I am running this on UBUNTU 12.04

Have installed docker and running ipython notebook on docker

Any help on this would be deeply appreciated

Thanks,
Sachi

Comment: Will you please run command `find / -name matplotlib` and check where the folder is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing software on an EC2 instance and should be moved to Unix&Linux, superuser, or serverfault.

Comment: Hi lafada, i did that. i just removed that instance of EC2 as it was causing lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I am on Redhat based linux on EC2, the way to solve the issue should be same.

Firstly you may check where does the matplot packages install.

Secondly you may check which sys.path does your python package installed. The issue might be that your install package was not included in the sys path.
Check sys path:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If your matplot or numpy package was not in the sys.path. You may consider to include the path to the sys path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('Your path of the matplot package')
```